# Regex search should not return anything if search string is empty in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

This returns values even if search is an empty string i.e.

```
const search = req.params.q; // " ";
const books = await Book.find({ title: { $regex: search, $options: "i" } });

//list of books
console.log(books);
```

How to not return any values if the search string is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an empty regex will match everything. If you want not to return anything when the search string is empty, then don't even run the `find` command. Change your code to account for an empty search string:

```
const search = req.params.q; // " ";
const books = search ? await Book.find({ title: { $regex: search, $options: "i" } }) : [];

//list of books
console.log(books);
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: I am currently using this. I could not gather anything more from the documentations. Thank you.

Comment: @PrajwolAdhikari This option also saves your database from unnecessary queries. When someone simply clicks the search button without entering anything, you don't even touch your DB.